# All my Chrome searches are redirected through www.getsearchredirecting.com

Tags: google-chrome, malware, redirection

Since recently (I don't know exactly when it started), all the searches I do on Chrome search bar are redirected through this site `www.getsearchredirecting.com`.

I did a malware scan with two common antivirus software and nothing.

I noticed it just because my workplace network started blocking my searches due to `www.getsearchredirecting.com` being on some unsafe list.

The same happens also if I use Chrome Canary, but not with non-Google browsers like Safari. I am on MacOs 12.4.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I would try deleting your Chrome user profile.  Your Chrome user profile is infected with malware.  If this system is connected to a enterprise network you should contact your IT Administrator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A colleague solved it for me.

It was a web colour picker extension for chrome:
https://extpose.com/ext/241212

Fortunately it was delisted.

Be careful out there guys, it's a bad world...

Comment: Had the same issue and the problematic extension is also an extension for picking colors "Awesome Color Picker". Strange coinscidence to say the least

Comment: Yeah, I had a color picker from chrome that was doing this.

Comment: Thank you, it was a color picker for me as well.

Comment: thanks! do you guys thing would be necessary to change passwords?